# Uploading NSData UIImageJPEGRepresentation too big

Tags: ios, nsdata

I'm uploading an image taken on the iPhone(Converted to NSData) via FTP on an iOS application using https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon.

```
dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
```

The problem is that the image size is about 40mb and every time the app finish uploading, Xcode Crashes. How can I make the image smaller?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will allow you to resize an image in Objective-C programmatically.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
     [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
     UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return newImage;
 }
```

Basically I recommend you resize the image and then upload it if the issue is the API you are using.  That being said, using the NSURLConnection class methods, I have been able to upload files larger than 40mb.  You can check out a post I just made out about how to use those methods to upload files with a PHP back-end here:

[Strange issue while posting image from iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923669/strange-issue-while-posting-image-from-iphone/16924389#16924389)

Make sure to mark my answer as correct if it helps!

Comment: My objective is to make the images smaller as possible, it is like profile pictures. Thank for the info Adam. I'll take a look to the php code. But, isn't easier to use AFNetworking?

Comment: It may be easier to AFNetworking.  I haven't really looked at the API although it looks interesting.  I mostly have just used NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection in the past. Thanks for sharing it!